# Assembler vs Entity Translator and Entities vs DTO

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, object-oriented-design, api, web-services

I was hoping that someone could explain the exact difference between an Assembler and Entity Translator.

Martin Fowler describes the [Assembler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) as a sort of Mapper(?) which converts DTOs into Domain objects and vice versa.

> When you're working with a remote interface, such as Remote Facade
>   (388), each call to it is expensive. As a result you need to reduce
>   the number of calls, and that means that you need to transfer more
>   data with each call. One way to do this is to use lots of parameters.
>   However, this is often awkward to program - indeed, it's often
>   impossible with languages such as Java that return only a single
>   value.
>
> The solution is to create a Data Transfer Object that can hold all the
>   data for the call. It needs to be serializable to go across the
>   connection. Usually an assembler is used on the server side to
>   transfer data between the DTO and any domain objects.

However, this description sounds  very similar to the [Entity Translator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647889.aspx).

> "Implement an entity translator that transforms message data types to
>   business types for requests and reverses the transformation for
>   responses.
>
> The entity translator is an object that is tightly coupled to message
>   data types and business entities, while providing loose coupling
>   between the consumers of the types. In other words, components of an
>   application use the translator to transform data types and the
>   translator has no knowledge about operations provided by the
>   application. This behavior provides the ability to change data types
>   on either end of the interaction without requiring changes to the
>   other end. The only component that needs to be updated is the
>   translator itself"

So this is a little bit confusing.

The reason why I'm asking this question is because I'm currently building out a client library which will allow me to retrieve/send data through remote REST API; however as I map this response data into my DTOs I had considered creating an additional anti-corruption(?) layer which will then map those DTOs into my Domain Models.

Basically, I would like to distribute these libraries via composer as a prepackaged module but still have the flexibility to swap them out should I find something better.

Another question I'd like to ask is how to differentiate between Entities + DTOs since Entity is a term which is often brought up whenever I discuss Data Mappers(which is how I'm currently structuring my client libraries).  Although I just referred to them as DTOs; the term "Entity" is often used to describe the type of objects you would either pass into or retrieve via the Data Mapper.

I suppose it's possible that I've been using Active Record pattern for far too long but the two of them basically just look like Anemic Domain Models me - ie: just getters and setters.

How do I properly distinguish between the two?

Comment: It sounds like you're taking the terms "Assembler" and "Entity Translator" too literally.  Those are just words that describe a concept; it's more important to understand the concept than it is to use the "right" word.  I've heard them called "Mappers" as well; in fact, there's a library called Automapper that does just that.  Focus on the concepts, not the terminology.

Comment: An Entity is something in the business domain that is modelled with a software object.  A DTO is just a container for some data that you want to move from one place to another; hence the name "Data Transfer Object."